# Import Paradox db to excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

I have Paradox database (its a file ) which i like to import into excel 2007 but i dont know how. After doing some research i found that i can do this in Ms access when i try to import the database in access i get following message "Unexpected error from external database driver ( 11010)"

Can someone please tell me how can i do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Linux, there is apparently an app called pxview. One of its options is px2csv, so it can create files that Excel can read. It can also output to SQL, which presumably Access can read.

http://pxlib.sourceforge.net/pxview/index.php